# Ubuntu 14.04 live disk only starts up with acpi=off

Tags: 12.04, boot, upgrade, 14.04, acpi

I recently tried to run ubuntu 14.04 on a USB drive as I wanted to decide whether it is worth upgrading to(my netbook now has 12.04 on it).

However, when I tried to start ubuntu up from the USB drive, it did not start up as the screen was stuck on "Disabling IRQ #9". Thereafter, through trial and error, I found out that it could start up after I enabled the "acpi=off" function. But, even though it starts up into the unity interface, it is stuck at a resolution of 800x600(my netbook monitor's native resolution is 1024x600) and it is very laggy. There was no such problem when I used 12.04 on a USB drive.

Therefore, I have three questions:

1) Why does my netbook always gets stuck at "Disabiling IRQ #9" ?

2) What is acpi=off?

3) How can I resolve the problem of the low resolution and very laggy GUI on acpi=off function?

Here is my netbook's system infomation:
NEC Versa N1100 Netbook, Intel Atom N270 with 945GSE Express Chipset, 1GB RAM, 160GB HDD, Ubuntu 12.04 dual boot with Windows XP

I would greatly appreciate your help regarding this issue, and thanks in advance :)

P.S. If you need more infomation to be able to help me solve this problem, please ask and also tell me how to get the info from my computer. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could someone please help? :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with a desktop pc. In my case the option "noapic" instead of acpi=off solves the problem of the low resolution but it creates a problem of (very very) slow internet connection.

Comment: Hi dome1970, I tried the option 'noapic' today, but unfortunately it doesn't work. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

Edit file with text editor program by adding `pci=noacpi` parameter into `syslinux.cfg` file in syslinux directory (/syslinux/syslinux.cfg) on your USB.

Example :

(Before)

```
label live
menu label live - boot the Live System
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append  file=/cdrom/preseed/custom.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.gz quiet splash --
```

(after)

```
label live
menu label live - boot the Live System
kernel /casper/vmlinuz
append  file=/cdrom/preseed/custom.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.gz pci=noacpi quiet splash --
```

Note : You can't edit it by running Ubuntu with that USB. But you can edit it by running another (CD/DVD/USB, Windows). See more information at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingACPI and try with other parameter.